# Interview: Find similar elements from two linked lists and return the result as a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm

This question was asked in an interview for my friend. The interviewer asked to find algorithm and code it in Java

**Question : Find similar elements from two linked lists and return the result as a linked list**

Eg: If linkedlist1 has 1->2->3->4->4->5->6 and linkedlist2 has 1->3->6->4->2->8

Resulted linkedlist 1->2->3->4->6

Thanks

Comment: @zengr Nope MSFT :), Anyways both the companies are on same lines in interview questions ;)

Comment: @codaddict they can be in any order, may not be sorted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find common nodes from two linked lists using recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707377/find-common-nodes-from-two-linked-lists-using-recursion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
return new LinkedList(new LinkedHashSet(list1).retainAll(list2));
```

This preserves the order as in `list1`. Of course someone might complain about this being cheating, if the questioner meant that you should build the algorithm yourself, but if the only restriction was "code it in Java", then this is a valid solution (and quite likely more efficient and bug-free than anyone's hand-made lower-level solution).

Comment: @Joonas Well interviewer asked for algorithm and then code it :). But ur solution is Handy :)

Comment: If the question was, as written above, "Question : Find similar elements from two linked lists and return the result as a linked list", then he didn't specifically ask for an *algorithm*.

Comment: @Joonas I changed the description now

Comment: Not acceptable. Question clearly asks for an algorithm "asked to find algorithm and code".

Answer (score 2):

Create a hash table.
Go through first  link list, mark entries as you visit them.   O(N)
Go through second link list, mark entries(different flag etc) as you visit them. O(M)

Traverse hash table and find all the entries with both LL member. Create new LL members as you find entries. O(H)

Total Complexity: O(N)+ O(M) + O(Max(N,H,M)) => O(N)

Note: Edited answer for Saurabh.

Comment: how come the complexity is O(N) , can you explain?

Comment: @Saurabh, the first traversal takes `O(n)` time, the second one takes `O(m)` time and the third one takes `O(n+m)` time. Assuming `n=m`, the overall algorithm is linear in the size of the lists.

Comment: Instead of a hash table, all you need is a hash set.

Answer (score 1):

get the first linked list and start from the first element , compare it with the first element of the second linked list , if they are same add the value to result and go to the second elemnt of first list, otherwise go to the second element of second list , do this until the values are same or you reach the and of second list.

Comment: o(n^2) solution. Very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet for constant time contains operation.

Iterate through the first List and add them to a HashSet --- O(n) 
(Note addding to HashSet is a constant time)

Iterate through second list and if hashSet.contains then add them to a result list.

At the end of the loop return the result list